# How to generate an R table() using duplicate values grouped by ID for use in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, duplicates

I have duplicate values for "Type" but they are associated with group ID codes.

```
Type <- data.frame("Type" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), 
                   "ID"= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4))
t <- table(Type[c("Type", "ID")])

a <- as.character()
```

I'm wanting to put this into a for-loop to generate a sentence.

```
for(i in 1:length(t)) {
  if(i == 1){
    a <- c(a,   
           paste0("One was associated with ", 
              names(t)[i], " (", 
              t[i]), "cases)")
    if(length(t) > 2){
      a <- paste0(a, ",")
    }
  }

  if(i < length(t) & i > 1){
a <- c(a,   
       paste0("one was associated with ", 
              names(t)[i], " (", 
              t[i]), "cases),")
  } else if (i == length(t)){
a <- c(a,   
       paste0("and one was associated with ", 
              names(t)[i], " (", 
              t[i]), "cases).")

  }
}

a <- capture.output(cat(a))
a
```

I've been playing around with

```
table(Type[c("Type", "ID")])
```

but now I'm stuck generating:

```
[1] "One was associated with  (3, cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (4 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (2 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), one was associated with  (0 cases), and one was associated with  (2 cases)."
```

Whereas I want my final product displaying as this:

```
[1] "One was associated with  A (3 cases), one was associated with B (4 cases), one was associated with C (2 cases), one was associated with C (2 cases).
```

I've had success manipulating the for-loop for various types of data but never any grouped data.

I went for this solution:

```
Library(Hmisc)
Library(stringi)

Type <- data.frame("Type" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), "ID"= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4))
t <- table(Type)
a <- as.character()
for(i in 1:nlevels((as.factor(Type$ID)))){
  a <- paste0(a,"one was associated with"," ", sep = "")
  for(j in 1:nlevels(as.factor(Type$Type))){
    if(t[j,i] > 0){
      a <- paste0(a,levels(Type$Type)[j]," (",t[j,i]," cases),",sep = " ")
    }
  }
}

a <- capture.output(cat(a))
a <- substr(a, 1, nchar(a)-2)
a <- paste0(a, ".")
if(length(table(Type$ID)) <3){
  a <- sub(",", "", a)
}
a <- stri_replace_last_regex(a, "one", "and one",  opts_regex = list())
a <- capitalize(a)
a
```

[1] "One was associated with A (3 cases), one was associated with B (4 cases), one was associated with C (2 cases), and one was associated with C (2 cases)."

And to test functionality:

```
Type <- data.frame("Type" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), "ID"= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

[1] "One was associated with A (3 cases) and one was associated with B (4 cases)."

Comment: How about `require(data.table);as.data.table(Type)[,sprintf("one was associated with  %s (%d cases)",Type,.N),by=list(Type,ID)]$V1`?

Comment: That (actually matrix()) is what I use to input this information into a chart but I don't know how to manipulate it for grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should iterate over the table (note that you should simply call a table of the df, nothing more) and then ignore nulls:

```
Type <- data.frame("Type" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), "ID"= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4))
t <- table(Type)
a <- as.character()
for(i in 1:nlevels((as.factor(Type$ID)))){
  a <- paste(a,"One was associated with ",sep = "")
  for(j in 1:nlevels(as.factor(Type$Type))){
    if(t[j,i] > 0){
      a <- paste(a,levels(Type$Type)[j],"(",t[j,i],"cases),",sep = " ")
    }
  }
}
```

the output is

```
[1] "One was associated with  A ( 3 cases),One was associated with  B ( 4 cases),One was associated with  C ( 2 cases),One was associated with  C ( 2 cases),"
```

and I'm sure you'll be able to apply the corrections for unneccesary spaces and commas.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, but then using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

sen <- Type %>% group_by(Type, ID) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(sentence = paste0("one was associated with ",Type," (",n," cases)"))
paste(sen$sentence, collapse = ", ")
```

Comment: this should be changed to `group_by(Type, ID)` for the desired output.  Another option for building the sentence is `sprintf("one was associated with %s (%i) cases", Type, n)`